# Failed to run C program cmocka unit test

Tags: c, unit-testing, cmocka

I tried to clone the below project and run it in my computer.

https://github.com/samvrlewis/cmocka-embedded-example

But got the below error.
I checked the cmocka is already installed in my computer.
When I run another project with cmocka test, I faced **the same clang error and could not execute the make command**.
**Is it because the cmocka setting in my computer? How can I fix it?**

(base) XXX@iMac test % **make**
../src/i2c.c
cc -I../src -Icmocka/include -c ../src/i2c.c -o obj/i2c.o
../src/tmp101.c
cc -I../src -Icmocka/include -c ../src/tmp101.c -o obj/tmp101.o
mock_i2c.c
cc -I../src -Icmocka/include -c mock_i2c.c -o obj/mock_i2c.o
test_tmp101.c
cc -I../src -Icmocka/include -c test_tmp101.c -o obj/test_tmp101.o
cc -o test_tmp101 obj/i2c.o obj/tmp101.o obj/mock_i2c.o obj/test_tmp101.o -Lcmocka/build/src -Wl,-rpath=cmocka/build/src  -Wl,--wrap=i2c_read_blocking -Wl,--wrap=i2c_transmit_blocking -lcmocka
ld: unknown options: -rpath=cmocka/build/src --wrap=i2c_read_blocking --wrap=i2c_transmit_blocking
**clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [test_tmp101] Error 1**

(base) XXXXX@iMac test % pkg-config --modversion cmocka

1.1.5

The cmocka lib file in my computer.

(base) iMac:lib XXXX$ ls
cmake           libcmocka.0.dylib   libcmocka.dylib
libcmocka.0.8.0.dylib   libcmocka.1.0.0.dylib   pkgconfig

Execute the make command and run the cmocka unit test.